# signature capture for android using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, signature

i want to perform an application in android using phonegap which captures the signature entered by the user and take a snapshot of it and stores and later on their next login it compare the signature with stored one and if matches it opens the application.Can anyone help me in acheiving this with some good links or examples?Some working examples will really useful.
thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know of a developer who's using [Signature Capture for Android](http://www.binarysolutions.biz/2010/12/signature-capture-for-android.html) from Binary Solutions to capture signatures in his PhoneGap app. Basically you'll need to call the signature capture code via an intent and you can do that by [creating an Android Plugin](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android) for PhoneGap.

Comment: hi simon thanks for the reply can you please elaborate with some working examples it will be helpful for me

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time to write up an elaborate example, I can only point you in the right direction. If you follow the links I provided in my answer you will be able to get signature capture working. I know this for a fact as I worked closely with another developer who integrated this into his app.

Answer (score 1):

I've done many research in this field, since I needed a plugin for doing the exact same thing as you.

The plugin I am currently using is this:
http://willowsystems.github.com/jSignature/#/about/

In my case it was necessary to be cross-platform since we're targeting not only Android but also iOS and WP. You can use it to save the signature to image and other formats.

Hopefully it will work for you, at least for the signature capturing, since the signature comparison is a totally different need.